# QGIS2.14: Attribute table values show "error" while Identify show results

Tags: qgis, sql-server

Using QGIS2.14 and using source data from a MSSQL Server 2016 instance I stumbled across a strange error.
My attribute table show all values as "ERROR"-values while using Identify shows up attribute values just fine. Below I have added a screenshot to illustrate my problem.

I have tried using ArcGIS10.4 as well. Attribute values show up, yet adding a 'ESRIOID' column.

Can someone identify the reason of this QGIS/SQLServer behaviour ?

[image: QGIS.214 window]

***EDIT**

Adding a primary key column without 'dot' values (like f.i. GBG.18) seems  to have solved the problem...